# Assessing DNA sequencing quality

Tags: histogram, bioinformatics

I work with a lot of bar charts. In particular, these bar charts are of basecalls along segments on the human genome.  Each point along the x-axis is one of the four nitrogenous bases(A,C,T,G) that compose DNA and the y-axis is essentially how many times a base was able to be "called" (or recognized by a sequencer machine, so as to sequence the genome, which is simply determining the identity of each base along the genome).
Many of these bar charts display roughly linear dropoffs (when the machines aren't able to get sufficient read depth) that fall to 0 or (almost-0) from plateau-like regions. Is there a straightforward algorithm for assigning these plots a score that reflects this tendency?  Is stdev a good place to start?

I'm a programmer but not much of a statistician.

Comment: I don't understand what's on your x-axis. If it's one of A,C,T or G then as that's categorical it's a bar-chart not a histogram, but then I can't see how you can have "plateau-like regions". Neither do I understand what you mean by "linear dropoffs". Could you link to an example histogram?

Comment: Not a brilliant example, but http://www.box.net/shared/f6bahdy81z.  Think of each point along the x-axis as a discrete unit along the genome that we try to determine the identity of.  We know each base exists, but we don't know whether it's an A,C,T, or G.  When we get a "call", it's basically a quality score that tells us how many times the sequencing machine was able determine the identity of the base.  Another dataset tells me what bases were "called".  For example, if there were a total of 100 calls for one base, and we had 98 T's called, 1 G called, and 1 A called, we would call that a T.

Comment: @mlxa What would this "score" mean?  How would it be used?  BTW, that plot may be deceptive due to the log scale: those aren't plateaux; they only appear to be so.  (A square root scale would be more appropriate for these data.)  The appearance of a long sequence of identical values around 185-210 shows this is not a straightforward problem: the nature of the variability, or lack thereof, is not a simple thing to characterize.

Comment: @whuber, also see http://www.box.net/shared/nbygq2x03u.  Why specifically would a sqrt scale be a better choice?

Comment: @mlxa I still have the same reaction and the same questions.

Comment: When the score drops to zero, it means the sequencer isn't able to determine the identity of the base.  If you've seen the double helix before, it means the sequencer can't figure out the identify of one half of a rung of the helix.  Certain regions of the genome are more difficult to characterize than others.  Bases (or x data points) with high numbers of basecalls, on the order of >=100, are able to be definitively identified.  Regions with 0 basecalls are of concern because then we've got to infer from neighboring regions what the identity of the low-read region could be.

Comment: I just tried Googling 'read depth' after looking in Wikipedia w/o success and found an answer on a sister StackExchange site (first time that's happened for me!): http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/638/what-is-the-sequencing-depth

Comment: 'Straightforward algorithm'? Perhaps not, but perhaps [hidden Markov models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model)? Not something I know much about, but i know they're used in bioinformatics (e.g. for looking for G/C-rich regions) and I know they're not that difficult to apply. I haven't thought this through yet so I'm not posting it as an answer for now!

Comment: @onestop, I'll look into them.  If you'd like, add that as an answer so I can upvote.

Comment: Do you want the score to reflect the linearity of dropoffs? Or do you just need a number that will roughly say how many bases could not be called reliably?

Comment: @Sheldon, the biggest concern is the magnitude and linearity of the dropoff.

Comment: I don't think stdev is a good option. It will give you some idea of the magnitude of change, but you won't know whether it's the magnitude of dropoff or magnitude of some other variability. It also won't say anything about linearity. What about something cheap and dirty, like trying to fit linear segments and seeing how many fit in a histogram, and their goodness of fit values?  How are you going to use the final score?

Comment: The score is used to evaluate the validity of the sequencing result for a particular genomic region.  Regions with many segments with bad scores are of concern.

Comment: @mlxa Properties of the binomial and poisson distributions indicate the variance of a count is roughly proportional to that count, whence the square root is a variance-stabilizing transformation.  This makes it legitimate to compare variability across different heights in the plot.  The log downweights variation in the high bars whereas using the raw data downweights variation in the lowest bars. // Since you're concerned about bad scores, why not just look at the proportion of bars falling below a critical threshold?

Comment: @mlxa Importantly, the appearance of "linearity" of the dropoff can change dramatically depending on the vertical scale.  That's another reason to pay close attention to the issue of how best to express the counts.  But you can finesse this by focusing on how many low "basecalls" there are and ignoring the pattern: maybe that would be good enough.

Comment: I'm still not clear what 'linearity of the drop-offs' means. Do you mean how how close they are to a straight line, regardless of its gradient, as I think we've been assuming? Or do you mean how close the changes in read depth are to vertical?

Comment: @whuber,onestop: I apologize for being imprecise. What's most concerning is when we see near-vertical dropoffs in read depth for segments that are otherwise displaying good read depth across bases.  In particular, some segments show dropoffs from regions of roughly 1000 read depth to zero for x bases.  I've studied Markov chains previously but not HMMs, which are apparently pretty widely used in bioinformatics to make inferences about the properties of certain genomic regions.  For this question though it appears best metric may be a simple normalized score reflecting bases with 0 read depth.